# Is there a way to automatically use minty for all code blocks?

Tags: minted, rstudio, rmarkdown

I have been given a book in `RMarkdown` format and I am compiling it to pdf using `RStudio`. I want to use `minted` for the many code blocks included in the book. It works fine but I would like to apply a certain style to all code blocks without having to add `\begin{minted}{} \end{minted}` to every code block. Is there a way to auto apply the minted formatting as a default?

Comment: Do you know that Rmarkdon can use ten highlight code styles without using LaTeX code directly? It could be as simple as add  some like `highlight: zenburn` to the pdf_document output

Comment: I wasn’t aware of that. Will have a look. Thank you @Fran

Comment: It makes sense to use the minted latex package, if the goal is to create a latex or pdf document; because of the additional options available within latex (see this thread for a detailed discussion https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4117).